# How to add a semicolon on all unclosed lines in a css file in vscode?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio

I need some search and replace method that checks if there is or there isn't a semicolon at the end of a css file style line, and if there isn't than one will be put.

Tried this: [\w\d]$ regex, that finds all unclosed lines but, there is no way I know of to add to it a ';' in the replace.

Also tried 'colonized' extention on VSCODE but it doesn't have the function I'm looking for. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post an example you would like to fix?

Comment: If your coworker's code has errors, why can't they correct them themselves? By the way, you do know that semicolons are optional before a `}` right?

Comment: I want some search and replace method that checks if there is or there isn't a semicolon at the end of a css file style line, and if there isn't than one will be put.
I know they are optional and I know I can ask my coworker to pay attention..
But I want something that is bulletproof.

Answer (score 0):

You could try these plugins:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chrisvltn.vs-code-semicolon-insertion
Adds a shortcut to insert a semicolon at the end of the line.
By pressing ctrl+shift+; the plugin will insert a semicolon at the end of the line and add a new line just after it.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=seunghwan.smartsemicolon
This extension places semicolons at the end of an expression, and other functionalities.

**For the auto completion**

In Settings, go to Extensions > CSS and check the Complete Property With Semicolon option.

If you prefer JSON, set css.completion.completePropertyWithSemicolon to true.